# scss class not applied

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I have recently moved to front end development and introduced to SASS. I am trying to apply following properties to the css class - link but the component is not getting the properties. Any input is highly appreciated.

## html :

```
<div _ngcontent-ype-26="" id="body">
  <svg width="1440" height="538">
    <g transform="translate(240,20)">
      <path class="link" d="M 180 114.92307692307692
                 C 90 114.92307692307692,
                    90 229.84615384615384,
                    0 229.84615384615384">
      </path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

## scss file :

```
.link path {
fill: none;
stroke: #ccc;
stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: There's really nothing in there that uses any SCSS features. You could do that just as easily with regular CSS. Are you trying to learn SCSS without getting a basic understanding of CSS first? That's probably not a good idea.

Comment: SCSS is already implemented in my project by someone. So I have to pick it up as soon as possible. I have a basic understanding of CSS. but even with a simple css this isn't working. any inputs? Edit: Sorry, I didn't know it's you who provided the second answer. :)

Comment: Your comment to one of the answers stated *It was 4 levels div -> svg -> g -> path -> link*. If that is how your SVG is structured (*note:* the code given in question doesn't follow this structure) then no you can't style your `path` depending on the `link` as there is no parent selector in CSS (even Sass/SCSS eventually has to compile into CSS). You'd need to just try `path` or `g path` or `div svg g path` or whatever suits you.

Answer (score 2):

Your SCSS would apply to a `path` element that is a child of an element with the class `link`. In your case, your `path` element *is* the element with the `link` class. So, your SCSS should look like this:

```
path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use your browser's developer tools to see what styles are being applied?

Comment: yeah I know it :) I'm sorry. I copied this html code from dev tools, generated from a d3 js code when embedded in angular 2. When I apply to plain html, it does apply but since this html is generated out of a javascript code, it fails to apply the same.

Comment: @abhi Have you converted your scss file to css before testing?

Answer (score 1):

You might try path.link instead of .link path as your selector

Comment: no it's still not working.. It was 4 levels div -> svg -> g -> path -> link. I am guess if that has anything to do here.. Any idea how to handle such  a case?